# How to show and hide common header in ng-view which is out of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to have a common header outside `ng-view` and I also need to show and hide it from the controller. I am trying to do the following task but unable to achieve

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div id="titleHead" ng-show="{{th}}">
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
 </div>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

js:

```
controller1($rootScope){
   $rootScope.th = 'true';
}

controller2($rootScope){
   $rootScope.th = 'false';
}
```

Please see my [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qp99V6IKfElOD5Z0PSTK?p=preview).Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: don't use `{{}}` interpolation in `ng-show` directive, it should be `ng-show="th"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML should be:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div id="titleHead" ng-show="th">
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
 </div>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
controller1($rootScope){
   $rootScope.th = true;
}

controller2($rootScope){
   $rootScope.th = false;
}
```

If you use `$rootScope.th = 'false';`, it has string value is `false`. When you check with `ng-show="'false'"` it will show.

Comment: I tried as you said but ng-show is not working as expected

Comment: Can you give me, example link?

Comment: please visit my example link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qp99V6IKfElOD5Z0PSTK?p=preview)

Comment: Please review my answer, I follow it and demo working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/clwPOAn9Y64b7lmmW89w?p=preview